# Sorting a map of >50k entries takes too long. Is there a quicker way to sort a Map in dart?

Tags: sorting, dart

I have a probability values returned from a neural network. The size of list returned is 50,257, so there are a lot of values. The list looks like`[-126.32508850097656, -126.77257537841797, -127.69950866699219, -129.98387145996094, ......]`

I need the top K values and their indices. So I converted the list to a Map:

`final temp = outputLogits.asMap();`

and then sorted them using:

```
var sortedKeys = temp.keys.toList(growable: false)
      ..sort((k1, k2) => temp[k2].compareTo(temp[k1]));
```

It produces the desired result, but the issue is that it takes way too long.

Am I doing this wrong? is there a more efficient way to get the same result?

further details:

The unsorted list looks like this:

```
[-126.32508850097656, -126.77257537841797, -127.69950866699219, -129.98387145996094, -128.03782653808594, -128.08395385742188, -126.33218383789062, -126.6927261352539, -127.6688232421875, -126.58303833007812, -127.32843017578125, -126.1390380859375, -126.54962158203125, -126.38087463378906, -127.82595825195312, -126.3281021118164, -125.81211853027344, -126.20887756347656, -125.95697784423828, -126.07755279541016, -126.35894012451172, -126.70021057128906, -127.03215026855469, -126.67304992675781, -126.92938995361328, -126.64434814453125, -128.20814514160156, -127.24195861816406, -128.25816345214844, -126.73397827148438, -127.62574768066406, -128.8334197998047, -124.46258544921875, -126.03125762939453, -126.18477630615234, -125.85749053955078, -126.11980438232422, -125.64325714111328, -126.06704711914062, -126.35154724121094, -124.83910369873047, -126.90412902832031, -126.02999877929688, -126.60641479492188, -125.97348022460938, -126.56074523925781, -126.58230590820312, -126.49268341064453, -128.5759735107422,
```

I need to find the top 40 probabilities, and their index and I achieve this using:

```
final temp = outputLogits.asMap();                            // converts the above list to a Map<int, double>
    // sort the map values descending
    // then take the largest 40 values
    var sortedKeys = temp.keys.toList(growable: false)
      ..sort((k1, k2) => temp[k2].compareTo(temp[k1]));           
    final Map<int, double> sortedMap = {};

    for (final key in sortedKeys.take(40)) {                    
      sortedMap[key] = temp[key];
    }
```

after sorting this is what `sortedMap` looks like:

```
{198: -117.52079772949219, 383: -118.29053497314453, 887: -119.25838470458984, 1119: -119.66973876953125, 632: -119.74752807617188, 628: -119.87970733642578, 554: -119.88958740234375, 1081: -119.9058837890625, 843: -120.10496520996094, 317: -120.21776580810547, 2102: -120.23406982421875, 770: -120.31946563720703, 2293: -120.40717315673828, 1649: -120.44376373291016, 366: -120.47624969482422, 2080: -120.4794921875, 2735: -120.74302673339844, 3244: -120.89102935791016, 2893: -120.97686004638672, 314: -120.98660278320312, 5334: -121.00469970703125, 1318: -121.03706359863281, 679: -121.12769317626953, 1881: -121.14120483398438, 1629: -121.18737030029297, 50256: -121.19244384765625, 357: -121.22344207763672, 1550: -121.27531433105469, 775: -121.31112670898438, 7486: -121.3316421508789, 921: -121.37474060058594, 1114: -121.43411254882812, 2312: -121.43602752685547, 1675: -121.51364135742188, 4874: -121.5697021484375, 1867: -121.57322692871094, 1439: -121.60330963134766, 8989: -121.60348510742188, 1320: -121.604621
```

I need the top value and their respective index thats why converted to Map

Comment: Can you provide a small example with some data and the expected result? The reason is I need to try understand the need of using a `Map`. Also, you could properly skip a lot of lookups in the map by using `entries` instead of `keys` but again, I would like to understand the problem a little more before recommending anything specific.

Comment: @julemand101, I've added the code in that I am trying to replicate. Basically, the model returns logits for each vocabulary [5027 in this case], and for text generation and to select the "next" word, the top 40 words having highest probability are needed, from which the next word is selected to continue the text generation

Comment: Please provide a minimal example showing what you have as input before the sorting and what you want as output from the sorting. I am not going to lean Kotlin and read multiple pages of an article in a topic I have no interest in, just to provide you with the best way to sort a list...

Comment: @julemand101, aah, understood. Sorry just wanted to give full context of what I'm trying to achieve as you asked why I converted to Map, was not trying to be lazy :). I've added more details to my question. Is this fine?

Comment: Yes that looks fine. I will come with an answer as soon as I have a working example for you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
void main() {
  final temp = [
    -126.32508850097656,
    -126.77257537841797,
    -127.69950866699219,
    -129.98387145996094,
    -128.03782653808594,
    -128.08395385742188,
    -126.33218383789062,
    -126.6927261352539,
    -127.6688232421875,
    -126.58303833007812,
    -127.32843017578125,
  ];

  final filteredLogitsWithIndexes = Map.fromEntries(
      (temp.asMap().entries.toList(growable: false)
            ..sort((e1, e2) => e2.value.compareTo(e1.value)))
          .take(5));

  print(filteredLogitsWithIndexes);
  // {0: -126.32508850097656, 6: -126.33218383789062, 9: -126.58303833007812,
  // 7: -126.6927261352539, 1: -126.77257537841797}
}
```

This should save you a lot of time since we don't need to make a lookup in the map for each comparison (since a `MapEntry` contains both `key` and `value`).

Comment: Thank you so much, this is indeed considerably faster  <3

Comment: sorry to ask again but is it possible to further optimize this task? I'm writing an NLP app that generates text and right now its taking about 5 seconds to write a word. So just asking if it would be possible to further increase sorting speed even by a little that would shave a second off? Thanks

Comment: @StuckInPhDNoMore Can you link to some example project with included test data which shows the current performance? It might make it easier for me to analyze where the performance issues are and try make optimizations. You are also welcome to contact me directly by using the mail on my github profile (you need to login to see it): https://github.com/julemand101/

Comment: so I did some debugging and looks like it was the tensorflow model inference that was taking up most of the time. Many thanks for your help. :)